# Delphi: Coloring TListView

Tags: delphi, tlistview

I am trying to assign multiple colors like a gradient to text in TListView, i tried searching but on the internet all i was able to find was the single color method, i tried with drawing one character at a time and changing colors but that does not work either. Here is the code i tried.

```
procedure TForm1.lvMainAdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var txtWidth: Integer;
    Rct: TRect;
begin
  Rct := item.DisplayRect(drBounds);
  lvMain.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
  DrawText(lvMain.Canvas.Handle, 'asd', 3, Rct, DT_SINGLELINE);
  Canvas.Refresh;
  lvMain.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  txtWidth := Canvas.TextWidth('asd');
  Rct.Left := Rct.Left + txtWidth;
  DrawText(lvMain.Canvas.Handle, 'b', 1, Rct, DT_SINGLELINE);
  lvMain.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
  txtWidth := Canvas.TextWidth('b');
  Rct.Left := Rct.Left + txtWidth;
  DrawText(lvMain.Canvas.Handle, 'sa', 2, Rct, DT_SINGLELINE);
end;
```

It still result in a single color. any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you'll have to take over the Windows `Paint` and `PaintRegion` methods to do it well (with a genuine gradient).

Also, set *`DefaultDraw`* to false before you return, or all the work you just did will be overwritten...

Comment: Any examples? or link to one?. Thanks